# How configure script decides to regenerate itself

Tags: autoconf, configure

When I run ./configure sometimes it decides that it's too old and re-runs autoconf through missing script to regenerate itself. Sometimes it leads to weird breakages since autoconf on
the target machine is older then autoconf that was used to originally generate configure.

I was wondering how it figures out that it's too old? Is there a standard way for configure to do that? or it depends on the library. Pointers to documentation would
be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`configure` does not decide this: `make` does.  If the `configure` script is older than `configure.ac` or any of the files it includes (starting with `aclocal.m4`), then `make` runs `autoconf` to rebuild `configure`.

Similar rules exist to rebuild `aclocal.m4` using `aclocal`, and the various `Makefile.in` using `automake`.

These rebuild rules should never be triggered after you unpack a tarball on a target machine, because the timestamp of all these files in the tarball should be correct (`configure` newer than `configure.ac`, etc.).  So if this happens, either something is bogus in your tarball (like you did not use `make dist` or preferably `make distcheck` to generate it), or the user compiling the source code did something wrong (like copying the entire directory without preserving the timestamps), or there is something bogus in the target system (e.g. `make` usually fail to work properly on a NFS-mounted directory if the clock of the NFS-server is not synchronized with that of the client).

Another frequent source of unwelcome rebuilt is observed by people who keep the generated files in version-control system.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/CVS.html for a discussion about this if that is your case.

Comment: I would preemptively add that `AM_MAINTAINER_MODE` is not a solution. It just adds another point where breakage can occur. Don't keep generated files in source control and use `make distcheck` to build tarballs and you should be fine.

Comment: The culprit ended up being git, since it does not preserve timestamps configure.ac was checked out to be newer then configure. Need to look into the issue why we keep generated files under source control.

Comment: @KiRPiCH: Note also that with modern `automake`, you can usually go from `configure.ac` + `Makefile.am` to having everything ready to `./configure` by running `autoreconf -i`. No need to worry about running `aclocal`, `autoconf`, `autoheader`, `automake`, `libtoolize` and whatever else in the correct order. If that isn't enough, then make a script called `bootstrap.sh` (`autogen.sh` is another common name, but there's an obscure tool called `autogen`) that runs the autotools in the correct order.